# What are Croquembouche?

Tags: one-piece

[image]

[image]

**What are Croquembouche?**

They can speak.They are delicious.Big mom was fed these stuffs by Jinbe.
**Are they living beings**?

Wiki says:

> 'Jinbe then arrives and feeds Big Mom some **croquembouche *tourists***, returning her to normal.'
>
> 'Moscato attempted to calm his mother, promising to **get her croquembouche** as soon as possible,..'
>
> 'The shocked citizens continue to evacuate, and Jinbe suddenly appears from the Juice River with a pile of the **anthropomorphic croquembouche *tourists***. He throws the **croquembouche** into Big Moms' mouth, immediately satiating her. The *croquembouche are glad to be eaten if they are found to be delicious.'*

**How are they *tourists*? Are they living sweets?**

Comment: Its almost difficult to find things that are not living on Big Moms islands.

Comment: a Croquembouche in real life is a French dessert consisting of choux pastry balls piled into a cone and bound with threads of caramel. it was like the first insane dish Master Chef Australia consents had to do excluding *anything* Heston Blumenthal came up with that year

Comment: So their french? That explains everything actually.

Answer (score 2):

The croquembouche is a french pastry made by piling small pastries called 'chou' together in a cone and coating them with crunchy caramel.
It is often served as wedding or any celebration.

Here they are part of the living sweets populating the whole cake island.

Answer (score 0):

In whole cake island, everything is alive. So the croquembouche must be some kind of candy exist in the island. We still don't know what kind of devil fruit that big mom has been eaten but according to many fans, it appears she can extract life from living beings and transfer it to objects like candies. Big mom was wrecking havoc to find this special kind of flavor when Jinbe arrives. So croquembouche must be a candy which big mom gave life to it. That is why the candies were happy when big mom eat them.